# Proving a circuit of a graph will have an edge in common with a cycle of the same graph.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Prove, if possible, if an edge lies on a circuit in $G$, then the edge also lies on a cycle in $G$.

I attempted to find a counterexample but it seems pretty evident that this statement is true. The trouble I am having is how to show that it is in fact true.

The strategy I was attempting to use was to assume it did not lie on a cycle and to show a contradiction. I can't seem to come up with anything concrete in order to use this method (if this is even a viable method).

Path - A walk that does not include any vertex twice.

Trail - A walk that does not pass the same edge twice.

Circuit - A trail that begins and ends on the same vertex.

Cycle - A path that begins and ends on the same vertex.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd say that a direct proof is easier to do in this case - show that you can reduce the circuit into a cycle without removing the chosen edge from it. Or (almost equivalently) you can aim for a contradiction by supposing that the shortest circuit containing the edge is not a cycle and then showing that you can reduce it further.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your definitions correctly then generating a counterexample is fairly simple. I assume *circuit* to be an eulerian circuit which must touch all nodes and a *cycle* to be a closed trail that need not touch all the nodes.

Start with a circle with 6 nodes and number them 1-2-3-4-5-6, then 1-3-5-1 is a cycle that does not have any edge in common with the circle.

Comment: Hmmm. That may work. Is this a case of: All cycles are circuits but not all circuits are cycles? In that, we can say 1,2,3,4,5,6 is a circuit and 1,3,5,1 is a cycle that does not contain any common edges with the circuit. Thus, we have a counterexample?

Comment: On the contrary, in my set of definitions 1-2-3-4-5-6-1 is the circle (which of course is also a cycle) but 1-3-5-1 is also a cycle but it does not have an edge in common with the original cycle. If does not conform to your definitions of *circle* and *cycle* then you should state your definitions more clearly.

Comment: What was said was true (I believe), but it doesn't work for the proof. It isn't asking if an edge on a circuit is on a specific cycle, but any cycle of the graph. In your case, any edge of 1,2,3,4,5,6 would in fact lie on some cycle of the graph.

Comment: Then your definition of *circuit* (which is always a cycle in my definition) and *cycle* are obviously different. Please link to your definitions.

Comment: I edited the question to include the definitions I'm using. I didn't realize there could be different interpretations. Sorry about that!